Principles and Techniques in Combinatorics Chapter 1 Problem 87
For $n>4$, let $r(n)$ denote the number of interior regions of a convex $n$-gon divided by all its diagonals if no three diagonals are concurrent within the $n$-gon. For instance, as shown below, $r(4) = 4$ and $r(5) = 11$. Prove that $r(n) = \binom{n}{4} + \binom{n-1}{2}$ 
This is what I have been thinking. We divide the pentagon like so:
Click here to see it
Notice that there each intersection connects to 4 vertices. So we have $\binom{n}{4}$ total intersections. Unfortunately, this is where I am stuck. Let me know how I should proceed.

Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1258739/graph-theory-how-many-regions-of-an-n-sided-polygon-with-all-chords-added?noredirect=1 Also, your problem is closely related to number of regions when $n$ points on a circle are joined; if the answer to that problem is $R_n$, then $r_n=R_n-n$, so the solutions there also translate to your problem.
